# How can I create an overlay over an HTML5 video?

Tags: css, html, video

I have tried all the help provided but still can't get it to work.
I need the video to be `width: 100%` and `height: 500px` and when I tried other solutions provided
here it worked but the video was a centered square in the middle rather then wide screen.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You.

Here is what I tried: HTML:

```
<div class="header-unit">
<div id="video-container">
    <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
        <video id="video-overlay">gfgfgfgf</video>
        <source src="makak.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="http://Dimofinf.net/your-video-file.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
        <source src="http://Dimofinf.net/your-video-file.webm" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
    </video>hghgfhgh
</div>
<!-- end video-container -->
```

The SASS kokozino: SASS:

```
.header-unit 
   height: 500px
   border: 2px solid #000
   border-right: none
   border-left: none
   position: relative
   padding: 20px

#video-container 
   position: absolute
   z-index: 0 

#video-container 
   top: 0%
   left: 0%
   height: 100%
   width: 100%
   overflow: hidden
   position: absolute
   z-index: 1

video 
   position: absolute


video.fillWidth 
   width: 100%

#video-overlay
   position: absolute
   z-index: 2
   width: 600px
   height: 500px
   background: #333
```

Once again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add maximum value of the z-index (z-index: 2147483647;) in to your overlay element. this trick will solve your problem.

check out [this awesome fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/carmijoon/pZbkX/) example.

```
  #overlay {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 100px; 
  color: #FFF; 
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.3);
  width: 640px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 2147483647;
}

#v {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work. That's actually the one that I tried.

Comment: then it might be a problem with the browser. is that example working in your browser?

Comment: @Nymph the example in fiddler worked but the video is centered and not 100% width. Is there a way to make the example on Fiddler 100% width?

Comment: I got it to work. I placed         <video id="video-overlay">gfgfgfgf</video> under video-container and it worked lol. But I really appreciate your help. Thanx a bunch!